# How do I make a Global Menu in Android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I'm building an Android TV app with a side menu that lists the different parts of the application such as "Home, My Videos, Search, Settings" etc.  However, it's not clear how to do this.

The example Google provides shows the list items corresponding with the title of each row that is currently being displayed.

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/browse.html

The only way I have been able to add items to the list is by calling:

```
 mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());

 HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(i, "Category " + i);

 mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
```

where listRowAdapter is one of the rows being displayed.  For example, I want to be able to add a Settings item and then load a Settings fragment or Activity when the user selects it. I'm guessing the ListRowPresenter is not the way to go.

Most, if not all, TV apps do this, so I must be missing something.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check this tutorial about [Introduction 
– Android TV application](http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial) that provides easy to follow instruction regarding how to develop Android TV application. Here is the [github](https://github.com/corochann/AndroidTVappTutorial) of the tutorial. Lastly you can check the official Google [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-leanback) for their code implementation in Android TV.

Comment: Lastly, for additional information, someone created a [navigation Menu](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/creating-a-google-tv-sliding-navigation-menu.html) you might want to check it out. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out those links.